# Thread condition variables: un-acquired lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have this example in Python which demonstrates the use of condition variables.

```
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-2s) %(message)s',)

def consumer(cond):

    # wait for the condition and use the resource

    logging.debug('Starting consumer thread')

    t = threading.currentThread()

    cond.wait()

    logging.debug('Resource is available to consumer')

def producer(cond):

    # set up the resource to be used by the consumer

    logging.debug('Starting producer thread')

    logging.debug('Making resource available')

    cond.notifyAll()


condition = threading.Condition()

# pass each thread a 'condition'
c1 = threading.Thread(name='c1', target=consumer, args=(condition,))
c2 = threading.Thread(name='c2', target=consumer, args=(condition,))
p = threading.Thread(name='p', target=producer, args=(condition,))


# start two threads and put them into 'wait' state
c1.start()
c2.start()

# after two seconds or after some operation notify them to free or step over the wait() function
time.sleep(2)
p.start()
```

However, it raises a runtime error `un-acquired lock` on threads. I have an idea that I need to use `acquire` and `release` functions but I'm not sure about their usage and what exactly they do.

Comment: Where is the *condition*? When the consumer calls `wait` -- where is the thing it's waiting for? When the produces calls `notify`, where is the thing it's notifying people about? You can't use a condition variable unless you have a condition (called a "predicate").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Conditions are a wrapper around an underlying `Lock` that provide wait/notify functionality.  You need to `acquire` a lock before you can release it - which `wait` does under the hood.  Notably once it gets re-awoken, it *reacquires* the lock.  Thus mutual exclusion is ensured between acquiring and releasing, with `wait` "yielding" control of the lock, if that makes sense.

Instead of doing the acquiring/releasing manually, just use the `Condition` as a context manager:

```
def consumer(cond):
    with cond:
        cond.wait()

    logging.debug('Resource is available to consumer')
```

If for whatever reason you're stuck on a version of python without context managers, this is equivalent to:

```
def consumer(cond):
    try:
        cond.acquire()
        cond.wait()
    finally:
        cond.release()

    logging.debug('Resource is available to consumer')
```

Often you want to make sure that only one consumer gets awoken, so the following idiom is frequently used:

```
with cond:
    while some_queue.isEmpty():
        cond.wait()
    #get one from queue
```

Thus you could `notify` any number of consumers and the extra ones just go immediately back to sleep once the Queue is empty.

Comment: In Python 2.5 as there is not `with` statement, would I put `acquire` and `release` around the `wait` function?

Comment: You need to wrap things with `try/finally` to get the same semantics as a context manager, see edit.

Comment: What does this lock do and why do you need it?

Comment: A `Lock` ensures that only one thread can enter a given code block at a given time - aka mutual exclusion.  You "need" it only so far as that's how `Condition` works, I can't answer more than that.  Maybe what you're trying to do doesn't actually need a condition, but I can't really tell you that.

Comment: On [that website](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Using_Locks_with_statement_Context_Manager.php) they don't put the `cond.acquire()` into the try statement, and I would say they are right not do so : it makes it more understandable. When you don't know about it you are like "why would you have to put the `acquire` into the try statement?". And that is not a relevant question as you don't have to put it in there. By the way, the linked website helped me a lot in understanding threading in Python, hope it could help anyone else